# What is the best practice for setting user data through a cloud formation template on an AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu-16.04, amazon-ami, aws-marketplace

I am trying to create an AWS marketplace offering. I need to initialize the Ubuntu AMI with config values. Like the database connection and user credentials etc. I want to pass those in from the cloud formation template.

I am guessing I can either write a script to modify the config values on the linux filesytem and then pass the parameters to that script via cloudformation. Or I can use AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store for the config values. But even then don't I need to write a key for the AWS SDK to be able retrieve values from the AWS Parameter store. Also if I use the parameter store approach can the cloud formation template set the AWS Parameter store values?

Once this is setup and I upload the AMI and cloud formation to the marketplace everything should be setup so that the web server on the ami can connect to all the resources (RDS, Redis etc) without extra configuration. Does anyone have examples of how to do this?

Comment: I have the same question

Comment: You shouldn't use userdata for any credentials. Use IAM + Systems Manager to get the credentials.

Comment: As I explain above we are taking this approach to use Systems Manager to store credentials. However we are unable to access systems manager without using our AWS SDK key on the local system to access Systems Manager without writing that key to our config file. Seems like a catch 22.